# Produce something in a size

Tags: meaning

I need to order lumber of 5 meter in length to a factory. Would it be correct to say :

> Lumber must be produced in a length of 5 meter.

Comment: Note the correct spelling of **length**.

Comment: Why use produce? And fyi, when you order lumber, you have to specify what kind of lumber (wood), for instance, 3 by 4s [inches] posts or wall board. If you just say lumber and the  length, they will laugh (and believe me, the guys that work in lumber stores will laugh). You also have to specify the wood....it's complicated.

Answer (score 2):

If going to a lumber yard, there are a few things you might say:

> Please cut (it / the wood / the lumber) into 5-metre lengths.
>   I need the (it / the wood / the lumber) cut into 5-metre pieces.
>   I'd like each piece to be 5 metres long.

Note that we would also have to specify the *other* dimensions of the lumber. For instance, if we want 1x4, 2x6, 4x8, and so on, dimensions, each cut to the length specified.

Comment: Let me give an another example to explain what i want to learn . I just wonder if use of “in a length of...” is correct . For example is it correct to say: “ Aluminum foil must be produced in a thickness of 2 micron “.

Comment: @languagelearner It should be *2 microns* (plural) in that construction, but yes. The essential phrasing is correct. (As is *in a length of X Ys.*)

Answer (score -2):

A few choices (assuming 100 sticks):

I would like to order...

1. 100, **5-meter long** sticks
2. 100 sticks, **5 meters long each**
3. 100 sticks **of 5-meter length**
4. 100 sticks, **each, 5 meters in length**
5. 100, **5-meter sticks**